# How do I set the default formatter for XML in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I trying to format XML in VSCode but every time I hit `Shift+Alt+F` I get a popup saying "The is no formatter for 'xml' files installed" and offering [Cancel] or [Install Formatter..].

At last count, I'd installed 6, but it still just does the same thing.

Looking in Settings.json, I see:

```
"[xml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.vscode-xml"
},
```

And if I hover over the "redhat.vscode-xml" I get a tooltip saying:

```
Value is not accepted. Valid values: null, "vscode.css-language-features", "vscode.html-language-features", "vscode.json-language-features", "ms-toolsai.jupyter", "vscode.markdown-language-features", "vscode.php-language-features", "ms-vscode.references-view", "ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit", "vscode.search-result", "vscode.typescript-language-features", "vscode.configuration-editing", "vscode.debug-auto-launch", "vscode.debug-server-ready", "vscode.emmet", "vscode.extension-editing", "vscode.git", "vscode.github", "vscode.github-authentication", "vscode.grunt", "vscode.gulp", "ms-vscode.hexeditor", "vscode.image-preview", "vscode.jake", "ms-vscode.js-debug", "ms-vscode.js-debug-companion", "vscode.merge-conflict", "vscode.microsoft-authentication", "ms-vscode.node-debug", "ms-vscode.node-debug2", "vscode.npm", "ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers", "ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh", "ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl", "ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-recommender", "vscode.simple-browser", "vscode.testing-editor-contributions", "ms-vscode.vscode-js-profile-table", "GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github".(1)
```

Presumably, there's some way to add the list, which isn't being done automatically when the formatter is installed.

FYI, I'm using VSCode Insiders version if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce - after installing the red hat extension, it appears in the list of options for me for that setting. And if I don't have a formatter set, it prompts me to choose one and it is also in that list. I am using the regular version of VSCode.  Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling the extension.

Comment: @TimothyG. I uninstalled all the extensions I had installed in the "category:formatters xml" list, restarted VSCode and attempted to format some XML. It prompted, I installed the Red Hat formatter and it work fine. I'd previously tried uninstalling one extension at a time, but it it seems in wanted everything cleared out! Thanks.